# Trying to make Bootstrap Tab system lock in the viewport before wheel scrolls through each tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a Bootstrap Tab system lock in the center of the viewport before the mouse wheel binds to the section in order to scroll through each tab and its corresponding content pane, at the end of which the mouse continues to scroll through the rest of the page.

The following is the script I am using to scroll through each tab and pane of the system which works fine:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        // Move panel tabs with the mouse wheel
        $(".tabContentArea").bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (event) {
            if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                $('#tabContent > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');

                if (!$('#tabContent li:first-child').hasClass('active')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#tabContent > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');

                if (!$('#tabContent li:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        })
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

The problem is that depending where the mouse is positioned on the screen, as soon as the wheel scroll reaches the section the section locks and commences scrolling through the tabs and corresponding panes. If the mouse arrow is positioned near the bottom of the screen when this happens the whole tab system scroll through happens off screen and by the time the scroll reaches the end of the section, the tabs scroll has already completed and just carries on to the end of the page.

Trying to resolve this, I found jquery-visible https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible/ which I have tried to implement into the existing code to make sure the tab section is fully viewable before the tabs and their corresponding panes begin scrolling.

Amended code as follows:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {

        // Move panel tabs with the mouse wheel
        if ($(".tabContentArea").visible(true, false, 'both') {

            $(".tabContentArea").bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (event) {
                if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                    $('#tabContent > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');

                    if (!$('#tabContent li:first-child').hasClass('active')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('#tabContent > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');

                    if (!$('#tabContent li:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            (!$(".tabContentArea").visible(true, false, 'both') {

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
     })(jQuery);
</script>
```

So far it doesnt work so wondering if anybody could correct me or point me in the direction of a better method of doing this?